# SVG background-color is not showing in firefoex and safari?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using an svg for my navbar but somehow svg fill color is not showing in firefox or some of the mobile phone?

**Here is my svg code**:

```
<svg width="603" height="158" viewBox="0 0 603 158" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_b)">
<path d="M0 0.525391L603 0.525423V0.525423C589.552 0.525403 577.222 8.01149 571.018 19.9432L516.041 125.679C505.715 145.539 485.192 158 462.807 158H0V0.525391Z" fill="#ffffff"/>
<path d="M0.25 0.775391L596.99 0.775423C585.867 2.64133 576.105 9.61836 570.796 19.8278L515.82 125.564C505.536 145.341 485.098 157.75 462.807 157.75H0.25V0.775391Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.5"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_b" x="-10" y="-9.47461" width="623" height="177.475" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="5"/>
<feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Here is what I want :

I want my svg background color black something like this

[image]

But when I open this in Iphone or firefox browser it is showing my background color white?

**Here is the image how it is showing in Iphone or firefox**

[image]

**Someone help me out with this issue**

**Thank You**

Comment: Firefox does not support the BackgroundImage pseudo input for filters. You'll have implement it in a different way.

Comment: Looks like  a typo. Did you mean `in=BackgroundImageFix` instead of `in=BackgroundImage`? https://jsfiddle.net/0mkf5nyL/

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work ..

```css
div{width:600px; height:600px; background: white}
```

```html
<div><svg width="603" height="158" viewBox="0 0 603 158" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_b)">
<path d="M0 0.525391L603 0.525423V0.525423C589.552 0.525403 577.222 8.01149 571.018 19.9432L516.041 125.679C505.715 145.539 485.192 158 462.807 158H0V0.525391Z" fill="#000000"/>
<path d="M0.25 0.775391L596.99 0.775423C585.867 2.64133 576.105 9.61836 570.796 19.8278L515.82 125.564C505.536 145.341 485.098 157.75 462.807 157.75H0.25V0.775391Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.5"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_b" x="-10" y="-9.47461" width="623" height="177.475" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="5"/>
<feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: ok I find a way to do this just convert it svg to png and here you go.